# Display character in a random place on video ram

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, dosbox

I'm trying to display a character in a random place on the screen. I would really appreciate it if someone explained why this code doesn't work.

```
call frandom

frandom proc near         ;random fruit procedure
push ax
mov ah,2ch
int 21h
xor ah,ah
mov al,dl  ;save 1/100 seconds
mov bl,5
div bl

mov di,ax
mov AX,Data_segment_name  ;load the starting address of the data
mov DS,AX                 ; segment into DS reg.
mov ax,0b800h
mov es,ax
mov ax,'a'
stosw

pop ax
frandom endp
```

Comment: Make sure you have the correct video hardware configured in Dosbox: http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf#.5Bdosbox.5D

Answer (score 4):

VGA text memory includes an attribute byte. `mov ax, 'a'` will use black on black so not much to see. Try `mov ax, 0x0f61` for white on black.

Comment: I get symbol not defined @Jester

Comment: Use `mov ax, 0f61h` then.

Comment: Thanks it worked but I was expecting the letter a to appear but instead I got a weird symbol next to an orange brown color @Jester

Comment: Also make sure your `di` value is a multiple of 2, such as by doing `shl di`

Comment: O.k thanks a lot I tried :
shl ax,1     ;multiply by 2
mov di,ax 
like you suggested and it works now @Jester